# Sqlite3 - INSERT statements returns error code 5

Tags: ssh, sqlite

I am trying to insert fake data in my **sqlite** remote database (using ssh).

My query looks something like this:

`sqlite3 /path/to/db 'INSERT INTO hosts('id', 'first_seen', 'last_seen') VALUES ('someValue', DATETIME('now'), DATETIME('now')); sqlite3 /path/to/db 'INSERT INTO hosts_attr('id', 'name') VALUES ('1', 'someAttr');`

So I am **inserting** data in more than one table in **ONE** single batch.

This step is integrated in my test automation (it is used only for mocking) but sometimes my test **fails** - 2 times in 200 runs: `Remote command failed with exit status 5`.

My questions is how I could collect more **data** about the issue?
Is my approach a.k.a. query wrong?
Since this test only fails from time to time what could be the issue for this inconsistency?

I have read the docs about error codes in sqlite's [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#busy), but the explanation there is kind of limited.

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Maybe you need to set a `busy_timeout` https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html, which, as far as I know, defaults to 0.

Comment: That only fails sometimes? Think about what the shell does do all those single quotes and what the command line arguments passed to sqlite3 end up looking like...

Comment: Thanks for your replies!

How setting `busy_timeout` will actually resolve my problem? Do I really need it?

Yes, it fails only *sometimes* and there is no much difference between queries, so the problem is not in query syntax itself. It might be with how it is processed under the hood.